# How to change the uilabel text when animate an uiimageview

Tags: ios, uilabel

I had an UIimageview which animate images  and 
I had a uilabel which describes about the image
How to change the label content when we change the image

```
for (int i=0; i<[mutable_banner count]; i=i+3) 
        {
            NSLog(@"--------%d----------%@",i,[mutable_banner objectAtIndex:i]);
            addr = [mutable_banner objectAtIndex:i];
            addr = [addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            data_banner = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:addr ] ];
            img_banner = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data_banner];

            [images addObject:img_banner];  

        }   


        array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:images];

         NSLog(@"-array-----%d",[array count]);

        imgview_banner = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,364 ,164)];//364.164
       // [imgview_banner setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data_banner ]];  

        imgview_banner.animationImages=images;
        imgview_banner.animationDuration=30.0f;
        [imgview_banner startAnimating ];
        [view_banner addSubview:imgview_banner];
```

Comment: can you give code of image animation?

Comment: Give some code that you tried.

Comment: By animating images do you mean "displaying one bye one images at regular time interval"?

Comment: yes , but the images r retrieved from the web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store `description` of all images in an `NSArray` with same order as you add images in  `array`. For example, array[0]'s description in imageDescription[0] and likewise.

Then when you start image animation, along with that call this method

```
index = 0;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0f target:self selector:@selector(showDesc) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[imgview_banner startAnimating ];
```

Then define `showDesc()` method as shown below :

```
- (void)showDesc {
    self.label.text = imageDescription[index];
    index ++;
    if (index == array.count) {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Declare a variable `index` as global.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code, you're using `UIImageView` animations, the animation duration is 30.f seconds, so to change the `UILabel` text when any image will be changed, you'll need to set `NSTimer` with `timeInterval`of same duration you set for the animation, in timer's target function, you can change the label text accordingly, for this you may need to maintain `currentIndex` to show the text according to image, do some good condition, it'll help you.